# unbound 50% slower after upgrade from 1.5.8 to 1.6.7

Tags: linux, dns, ubuntu-18.04

I recently performed an OS upgrade, and along with it came an upgrade from  1.5.8 to  1.6.7 for unbound.

Looking at the unbound statistics before and after the upgrade I found a 50% increase in average recursion processing time.

Before:

```
Jun 13 10:39:43 proxy-1 unbound: [26309:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.105584 sec
Jun 13 11:39:43 proxy-1 unbound: [26309:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.116293 sec
Jun 13 12:39:43 proxy-1 unbound: [26309:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.109271 sec
Jun 13 13:39:43 proxy-1 unbound: [26309:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.145702 sec
```

After (comparable times during peak times, noon):

```
 Jun 15 10:02:41 proxy-1 unbound: [30571:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.170653 sec
 Jun 15 11:02:41 proxy-1 unbound: [30571:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.186744 sec
 Jun 15 12:02:41 proxy-1 unbound: [30571:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.181295 sec
 Jun 15 13:02:41 proxy-1 unbound: [30571:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.183084 sec
 Jun 15 14:02:41 proxy-1 unbound: [30571:0] info: average recursion processing time 0.179574 sec
```

Are there any changes between 1.5 and 1.6 drastically impacting the performance?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the sheer number of queries was causing unbound to slow down (without optimization).
I then implemented the optimizations outlined in https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/howto-optimise/
and query times dropped significantly.

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry this doesn't really answer but it does provide some investigation details*

---

I also noticed a slowdown in DNS resolution speed when upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 which upgraded unbound from 1.5.8 to 1.6.7, around 20% slower:
[image: Chart showing 20% increase in DNS resolution time]

I already had most of these optimisations flag and I don't have a huge concurrency, here's the configuration I use:

```
server:
  access-control: 127.0.0.1 allow_snoop
  access-control: ::1 allow_snoop
  val-log-level: 1
  so-rcvbuf: 4m
  so-sndbuf: 4m
  key-cache-size: 128m
  msg-cache-size: 128m
  rrset-cache-size: 256m
  prefetch: yes
  prefetch-key: yes
```

I tried adding some about threading mostly but it didn't help. After looking at the logs after a restart though I noticed this warning:

```
so-sndbuf 4194304 was not granted. Got 425984. To fix: start with root permissions(linux) or sysctl bigger net.core.wmem_max(linux) or kern.ipc.maxsockbuf(bsd) values.
so-rcvbuf 4194304 was not granted. Got 425984. To fix: start with root permissions(linux) or sysctl bigger net.core.rmem_max(linux) or kern.ipc.maxsockbuf(bsd) values.
```

Which wasn't present before the upgrade, so I tried increasing these values:

```sh
echo "net.core.rmem_max = 16777216" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo "net.core.wmem_max = 16777216" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -p
sudo systemctl restart unbound
```

No more warning after that but the performance is still the same, 20% slower than 1.5.8. I still haven't found the reason.